# Enable re-interval in gawk script

Tags: gawk, shebang

I create executable scripts for gawk by using the following #!:

> `#!/usr/bin/gawk -f`

However if I want to enable interval regular expressions I cannot seem to add `--re-interval` or `-W re-interval` in the #!.

> `#!/usr/bin/gawk --re-interval -f
> #Above doesn't work`

Is there a way to have a script activate this option without command line arguments, or a better way to enter the arguments so it works?

I am using cygwin if that matters for your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible. See http://hibernia.jakma.org/~paul/awk-faq.html#script-args for the reason and an alternative.

> **How do I pass options to AWK in a
>   bang-path?**
>
> Short answer is that you can't,
>   because the kernel won't parse a
>   bang-path past the name of the script.
>   The rest of the line is passed as a
>   single string, in the second argument.
>   I.e. this won't work:
>
> `#!/path/to/gawk --posix --re-interval -f`
>
> ....awk script..
>
> Instead, use a shell script, e.g.:
>
> `#!/bin/bash`
>
> `gawk --posix --re-interval -v foo=$1 '`
>   `BEGIN {   print foo } '`